# How to DRY url_helpers for nested resources and make them aware of the parent class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I can DRY up view code that contains links to the current object by doing something like

```
#helper
def current_url(new_params)
  url_for params.merge(new_params)
end

#shared partial
<%= link_to "JSON", current_url(:format=>:json) %>
```

But what if I need to link to a nested resource? For example, a polymorphic Comment model that is commentable to both a User and an Object model. This is set up with nested routes, so to link to a comments view I would use

```
#user view
<%= link_to "User's Comments", user_comments_path(@user) %>
#object view
<%= link_to "Object's Comments", object_comments_path(@object) %>
```

Is there a way to DRY this up without passing a local to a partial? I want something like

```
#shared/_comments_link.html.erb
<%= link_to "#{resource.class.name}'s Comments", #{resource}_comments_path(#{resource}) %>
```

But I can't see how to make the url_helper aware of what of the parent class is.

Answer (score 0):

a helper would look like this

```
def link_to_comments(resouce)
  name = "#{resource.class}'s Comments"
  path = send :"#{resource.class.name.underscore}_comments_path", resource
  link_to name, path
end
```